# Regex expression to match command output

Tags: regex

```
Filename                     EOF    

xxxxxxx        101           241434 12DEC2011  9:33 255,255 UUUU     14     42
xxxxxxx        101           114682 12DEC2013 11:49 220,0   UUUU     14     42
xxxxxxxx       101           200542 14DEC2011 14:43 255,255 UUUU     14     42
xxxxxxxx       101           200458 25JAN2012 15:28 220,0   NUUU     14     42
xxxxxxxx       101             8102 28JAN2015 15:17 227,12  NCCC     14     14
xxxxxx         101           114502 12DEC2013 11:49 220,0   UUUU     14     42
xxxxxxx        101             4622 23JAN2012 14:46 255,255 UUUU     14     42
xxxxxxxx       101              120 18APR2013 16:20 201,130 OOOO     14     28
xxxxxx         101            48298 03JAN2013  8:47  90,2   OOOO     14     14
xxxxx          101           200686 07DEC2011 15:59 255,255 UUUU     14     42
xxxxxxxx       101             3578 30JAN2014 18:14 255,255 UUUU     14     42
```

From the output i want to match Filename and EOF filename only. I tired with `\s\d+\s\d` and was able to match only the EOF but find little challeage to match filename with `EOF`

Comment: What program are you using to filter on your regexp?

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, could you put an example on what you expect to match for a line?

Comment: HI I am using HP OO to run a command in remote server

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
^([\w\.]+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)
```

Group 1 will contain FileName and Group 2 will contain EOF

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI7hM0/2)

Explanation:

`^` its an anchor that tells the engine this is the start of the line.

`\w` matches any word characters (alphanumeric and underscore)

`\s` matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks)

`\d` matches any digit character [0-9]

`+` matches 1 or more of the preceding token

`\.` matches the dot . character

`[...]` is a character set, that matches any character inside the set

`(...)` its a capturing group, that groups what is inside for extracting a substring

So with this in mind you can see what the pattern is doing:

You should tell the engine its a start of line `^` then you want to capture the first group of alphanumeric chars `([\w\.]+)` here I'm assuming the name of the file may contain a dot. If it may have other characters like -, you should change this part to `([\w\.-]+)` or whatever you may need to match.

Then we tell that the string will have at least one whitespace, but may have more `\s+`. then you tell it will have at least one digit, but might have more `\d+` (since you are not interested in this you don't put this in capture group) then more whitespacing `\s+` then more digits, but these you are interested in capturing, so you put this in parenthesis `(\d+)`.

Hope this helps you to understand a little more about Regex, Cheers!

Comment: This is working, could you help me to understand about the expression, still i am not able to understand the expression you have given, it will really help me in upcoming issues.

Comment: OK, im not in home now, ill explain in about a hour or so

Comment: Just edited, if you need more clarifications just point it out

Comment: you very much for your help. When I use that expression it also capturing 101 as well, can you please tell me how do I remove from the match.

Comment: You need to use capture groups, the implementation depends on the programming language you are using